# Can the Anymote library be implemented in a Google Chrome extension built on GWT?

Tags: gwt, google-chrome-extension, google-tv

I have built the UI for my Google Chrome Extension, but I am trying to figure out how to implement the anymote library within a GWT web-app. Is this even possible to accomplish?

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://plus.google.com/107890677565458476428/about

Comment: :)  Yes I am the developer working on Chromemote. Thanks though for the reply Leon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll be talking a bit more about this in an upcoming Google IO talk (6/28/2012).  The talk is about control from the second screen which will include Chrome Extensions.

https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/1301/

Comment: Excellent Dave! I am very excited for this. I will be attending a Google IO Extended meetup in Houston to watch the stream. Do you know whether or not this talk will be broadcasted live?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it done, but don't believe the source has been made available.

Comment: I have had a few developers tell me that it is impossible to implement the anymote protocols as a Google Chrome Extension. I believe it is possible and have been working non-stop to figure this out. Thanks for the feedback Les, at least now I know it can be done.

Comment: It was demonstrated today at Google I/O by Dave.  The stream video should be posted shortly.

Comment: Very exciting. I can not wait.